# How to use background url() in Stylus

Tags: stylus

How do you use the css equivalent of `background url()` in Stylus? `background url(image.png)` doesnt seem to be working.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesnt seem to be working"? See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGBQVY (Stylus 0.50.0, view compiled CSS), all works as expected.

Comment: Ah, looks like it was either getting hidden behind another element or was being rendered with a height of 0. Thanks for the response.

Comment: If having issues with base64 images inside `url()`, see [here](https://github.com/stylus/stylus/issues/1969), simply wrap the url in quotation marks.